# userPlaylists returns empty

Tags: ios, spotify

im working on a Spotify IOS app and i've been trying to get the users's playlists using
`[[SPSession sharedSession]userPlaylists]`

Most of the times, it doesn't return any playlists, occasionally, it does return all the playlists. I am logged in correctly since 
`[[SPSession sharedSession] starredPlaylist]`
and 
`[[SPSession sharedSession] inboxPlaylist]`
always return the playlist

Anyone have any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in CocoaLibSpotify is asynchronous — you'll need to wait until the `loaded` property of `userPlaylists` returns `YES` before the `playlists` property contains anything useful, and each playlist contained within has a `loaded` property that is set to `YES` when the playlist's name and track listing has been loaded.

All properties in the playlist stack (and elsewhere in CocoaLibSpotify) are Key-Value Observing compliant. The best approach is to observe the properties you're interested in, then react when they're set.

Comment: i do have loop that checks if the user playlist is loaded, but it still returns empty `code` if (![[[SPSession sharedSession] userPlaylists] isLoaded])
    {
        loginAttempts++;
        
        if (loginAttempts < 10) 
        {
            [self performSelector:_cmd withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
            return;
        }
    }
  
        NSLog(@"playlists %@",[[SPSession sharedSession] userPlaylists].playlists);`code`

Comment: In the nicest way possible… That is a *really* bad approach. Playlists can take a long time to load on a fresh login, especially if the user has a lot of them. I guarantee that if you make a loop like that that checks x times, you'll encounter a user whose playlists take x+1 to load.

Comment: oh ok thanks for that, So there is really no good way to load playlists?

Comment: Playlists are loaded automatically - you just need to use Key-Value observing to observe when that happens.